# Simple Question about Almost Sure Concept

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Here is a very simple scenario which bothers me a lot.

> Consider a discrete random variables $X(k)$ with index $k=1,2,\ldots,n$. I was wondering if $X(k) \le c$ almost surely for some fixed constant $c$, is it possible that the expected value of $X(k)$ violates the almost sure inequality above? i.e., is it possible that $E[X(k)] > c$ ?

Thank you

Comment: no, since expectation is an integral and thus monotone.

Comment: Why you are indexing the discrete random variables? Your question relates to only 1 of them if I see it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Let $S_k$ be the support of the probability mass of $X_k$; the set of all possible values that have non-zero probability mass (surely).

By definition of expectation of a discrete random variable:

$$\mathsf E(X_k) = \sum_{x\in S_k} x\;\mathsf P(X=x)$$

Now, since $X_k\leq c $ almost surely, then $\forall x\in S_k:x\leq c$.

$$\mathsf E(X_k) \leq c \; \sum_{x\in S_k} \mathsf P(X=x)$$

By the Law of Total Probability: $\sum\limits_{x\in S_k} \mathsf P(X=x) = 1$ so:
$$\mathsf E(X_k) \leq c$$

Comment: Thank you so much  @Graham Kemp, very clear explanation !!